# GAE basic scaling override memory limit

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am a cloud noob.
I have a node application with GAE. I am using basic scaling to serve up the requests. I have specified instance class B4_1G which has memory limit of 2048mb.(https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard#second-gen-runtimes)
The application is supposed to perform DOM scraping using Cheerio on some extremely large HTML files. This works well until the HTML that I need to scrape is beyond huge. Then I start getting memory error in logs :
Exceeded hard memory limit of 2048 MB with 2052 MB after servicing 1 requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.

Is there any way I can override the memory limit to say 4096mb or even more?
Setting the resources additionally in app.yaml did not seem to help.

Any help or pointers appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you provided shows the support instance sizes.

If you need more than 2 GB of memory you will need to switch to App Engine Flexible or a Compute Engine instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer John. App Engine Flexible seems like a good approach. I will try to use it and will post an update soon.

Comment: @SaurabhArora - I think you will like App Engine Flexible. Very easy to deploy with a number of benefits over AE Standard. One of them is being able to SSH into the instance while developing.

Comment: You can also use Cloud Run where you can use up to 8Gb of memory.

Comment: @JohnHanley, is it possible to shut down the flexible app engine when idle? The standard version allows the instance to serve up when a request comes and then shuts down, hence, saving a lot on billing.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, Thank you for your comment. The process is quite a long running process and Cloud Run, despite of memory advantage, times out (at an hour) on substantially huge documents. Any option to increase the time quota on a cloud run?

Comment: Did you have a look to autopilot? It could fit your use case.

Comment: App Engine Flexible does not scale down to zero. This is a managed service running on a Compute Engine instance. The startup time for the VM is too long to meet the service requirements. If scale to zero is a requirement, Cloud Run is usually a great option and of course Compute Engine for absolute control over everything.

Comment: App Engine under the covers is a container-based application. Cloud Run is a fully managed serverless container platform. The big brother to both App Engine and Cloud Run is of course Kubernetes. However, Kubernetes is a cluster and would not meet your scale to zero requirements. If I was developing a new application for the best balance of a managed service, price, performance, high availability, and ease of development, I would choose Cloud Run.

Comment: And of course, Cloud Run scales to zero automatically.